# AppleScript for iTerm2 to activate or create session

Tags: macos, applescript, iterm2

I'm trying to write an AppleScript for iTerm2 that for a fixed profile ("session"?) name, let's say "Dev Server", checks whether there is a tab with that profile in any window (or just the current window if that's easier). If any such tab exists, I'd like to activate ("select") it. If there's multiple tabs with the same session, the selecting any one of them is fine. If there is no tab with that session name, I'd like to create a new tab in the current window with that name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
tell application "iTerm"
    tell current window
        set foundProfile to false
        repeat with aTab in tabs
            set profName to profile name of current session of aTab
            if profName is "Dev Server" then
                select aTab
                set foundProfile to true
                exit repeat
            end if
        end repeat
        if not foundProfile then
            create tab with profile "Dev Server"
        end if
    end tell
end tell
```